# How to replace some of text in href of Anchore tag in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor

I have few anchor with URL like "http%3a//test.dev.test.com/posts/test test", i want to replace it with "http://test.dev.test.com/posts/test test" on window load function, i have tried below code for this but it is not updating the URL of anchor tags.

```
 $('a[href*="http%3a//"]').each(function () {
      this.href = this.attr('href').replace('http%3a//', 'http://');
    });
```

i am not getting why it is not working. please help me.

EDIT::

```
<a href="http%3a//test.dev.test.com/posts/test test" rel="bookmark" class="aChangeUrl" id="ctl00_lnkEntry">New test in March</a>
```

Comment: Can you show your HTML as well??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`attr` isn't a native DOM method but a jQuery one.

Change

```
  this.href = this.attr('href').replace('http%3a//', 'http://');
```

to

```
  this.href = $(this).attr('href').replace('http%3a//', 'http://');
```

Note that you can make the whole a little cleaner and simpler :

```
$('a[href^="http%3a//"]').attr('href', function(_,s) {
     return s.replace('http%3a//', 'http://');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `.attr()` function's receiver function to make your job easy,

```
$('a[href*="http%3a//"]').attr('href', function(i,href){
      return href.replace('http%3a//', 'http://');
});
```

---

Reason for the error that you are facing:

```
this.attr('href')
----^ Here comes the problem. 'this' will point a native javascript
object at this context and it doesn't have a member function called .attr().
```

Comment: Great use of the anonymous function!